# UIStackView doesn't fill if removing and adding the same views

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I found an issue in iOS 9 where the layout is not working properly when removing and adding the same views to `UIStackView` and uses intrinsic content size of the views instead of the specified `fillEqually` distribution type.

For example, this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stackView = UIStackView()

    let red = UIButton()
    let blue = UIButton()
    let green = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

        red.backgroundColor = .red
        blue.backgroundColor = .blue
        green.backgroundColor = .green

        let views = [red, blue, green]

        for view in views {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
        }

        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.frame = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: view.frame.height / 3)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(button)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func buttonClicked() {
        for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(red)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(blue)
    }
}
```

Shows the following result after tapping the screen:

[image]

But on iOS 10 it shows the expected result:

[image]

Creating new views instead of reusing the old ones outputs the expected layout on iOS 9:

```
func buttonClicked() {
    for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let red = UIButton()
    let blue = UIButton()
    red.backgroundColor = .red
    blue.backgroundColor = .blue

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(red)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(blue)
}
```

But the whole point of this code is reusing views to improve performance.

Is this an issue in my code? A bug on iOS 9? Is there any known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by explicitly calling `layoutIfNeeded` method after removing all the views:

```
func buttonClicked() {
    for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    stackView.layoutIfNeeded()  // Required to avoid layout issues in iOS 9

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(red)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(blue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
    stackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I think you forget to call `removeArrangedSubview`.

Comment: No change. I was calling it before, but removed it because the docs say that 'To remove the view as a subview, send it -removeFromSuperview as usual; the relevant UIStackView will remove it from its arrangedSubviews list  automatically.'